# Uploading multiple images to the server and inserting their file names in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have the following codes to uploade multiple images to the server and inserting their names in a database.

CONTENT PAGE

```
 <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
    protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

       if (UploadImages.PostedFile != null)

       {

        string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            con.Open();        

           foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in this.UploadImages.PostedFiles)
           {
                string newname = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd-hhmmss-") + uploadedFile.FileName;
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images/Editors/BG/"), newname));
                listofuploadedfiles.Text += string.Format("<br /><img width='100px' src='/Images/Editors/BG/{0}'/>{0}<br clear='all'/>", newname);


               cmd.Connection = con; 
               cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BackgroundImages([BG_fileName], [IDuser]) VALUES(" + newname + "," + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() + ")";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error while inserting record on table..." + ex.Message + "Insert Records");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

         }

        }

   }
```

I'm able to upload the images to the server but nothing is added to the database. I'm not getting any error. What's wrong?

In fact I translated myself the above code from VB to C#. I'm sure I've missed something since I'm not very familar with C# yet. The following VB code works well:

```
Protected Sub uploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If UploadImages.HasFiles Then

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            con.Open()

            Dim newname As String

            For Each uploadedFile As HttpPostedFile In UploadImages.PostedFiles

                newname = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd-hhmmss-") + uploadedFile.FileName
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), newname))
                listofuploadedfiles.Text += [String].Format("<br /><img width='100px' src='Images/{0}'/>{0}<br clear='all'/>", newname)

                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images([filename], [userid]) VALUES('" & newname & "','" & userid & "' )"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you need to bind parameters with that.

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

       if (UploadImages.PostedFile != null)

       {

           string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        try
        {             

           foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in this.UploadImages.PostedFiles)
           {
                string newname = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd-hhmmss-") + uploadedFile.FileName;
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images/Editors/BG/"), newname));
                listofuploadedfiles.Text += string.Format("<br /><img width='100px' src='/Images/Editors/BG/{0}'/>{0}<br clear='all'/>", newname);


              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
              cmd.Connection = con;
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO BackgroundImages(BG_fileName, IDuser)
              VALUES(@param1,@param2)";  

              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", newname);  
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error while inserting record on table..." + ex.Message + "Insert Records");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

         }

        }

   }
```